# Dynamic Content / CMS

Tags: dynamic, content-management-system

I'm new to CMS or dynamic content. I've looked at Wordpress and Joola but I was wondering if it is possible to build an entire site in Dreamweaver and then add a section on the homepage which can be updated by the admin?

For instance, the homepage might have a recent news section which the site owner can update on their own, but the rest of the homepage and the site is built in Dreamweaver?

Sorry if my question is ridiculous...

Cheers,
Colm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tools that allow you to create the site however you normally do then mark a certain part of the page as "editable" by the client.

Here are a few:

cushycms.com (already mentioned by TomcatExodus)

surrealcms.com

snappysnippets.com

pagelime.com

Another option (disclaimer: who I happen to work for) is http://designhamster.com. We're similar to the above services except that we also provide hosting.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is a free software package that allows anyone to easily publish, manage and organize a wide variety of content on a website.
Manage content with an easy-to-use web interface. Drupal's flexibility handles countless content types including video, text, blog, podcasts, and polls with robust user management, menu handling, real-time statistics and optional revision control.

Comment: The problem is, I have the entire site designed on paper. I want lavalamp menus and I have tonnes of fancy CSS and JS effects planned. I don't want to have to adhere to any themes / templates whatsoever. I also don't have time to learn a new software package. So is it possible to design my site in Dreamweaver, then add the updatable section later?